# ¿Como pasar codigo Java a Python?

Tags: java, python-3.x, bucles

Tengo en Java la siguiente porción de código:

```
public static void piramideNumeros() {//Piramide de numeros
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int n;
     System.out.print("Ingrese un numero: ");
     n = sc.nextInt();
     for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
          System.out.println("");
          for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
               System.out.print(j + " ");
          }
     }
     System.out.println("");
}
```

El cual me retorna en consola la pirámide de la sig. forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me gustaría hacer el mismo programa pero en Python, lo que he tratado de hacer es lo siguiente:

```
def piramideDeNumeros():
     n = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
     i = 1
     j = 1
     for i in range(i, n+1):
         print("\n")
         for j in range(j, i+1):
             print(j," ")
     print("\n")
```

Mas sin embargo no logro retornar en consola la pirámide tal como en Java. Esto es lo que me imprime la consola con el anterior código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y alguien me pueda ayudar, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu problema surje porque la función `print()` tiene una serie de parámetros, que si no los pones tienen valores por defecto.
Entre esos parámetros está `end` que por defecto es `'\n'` por lo que siempre habrá un salto del línea al final, salvo que especifiques otra cosa.

Hacer: `print("un texto")`
es lo mismo que hacer: `print("un texto", end='\n')`

Así que podrías cambiar ese parámetro en el segundo `for` para que sea simplemente un espacio.

Otra cosa que tienes mal es el uso de `i` y `j` en los ciclos, porque los usas como iteradores, pero también como primer componente del rango. Eso está mal, porque en cada iteración el valor cambió. Si siempre inician en 1 debes poner directamente ese valor.
Algo así:

```
def piramideDeNumeros():
     n = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
     for i in range(1, n+1):
         for j in range(1, i+1):
             print(j, end=" ")
         print()
```

Comment: la competencia es dura para responder :v me doy la vuelta un rato y la respuesta ya esta escrita, me parece que está muy bien explicado.

Comment: Tu respuesta me fue de mucha ayuda, habían conceptos que no sabia que existían, gracias por aclarármelo, te lo agradezco mucho.